# How do I create a radial metallic gear material procedurally?

Tags: materials, procedural

I am trying to make a gear material where there are highlights that are like lines facing outward from the gear's center. This image shows what I am trying to accomplish. How can such an effect be done?

[image: Gear]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Voting to reopen this as I interpret it to be about the bump map to create this pattern, not necessarily anisotropic shading.

Comment: Yeah, I'll second that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here I'm converting *Generated Coordinates* to something like *Object Coordinates* so this should work on any size of gear.

A *Gradient Texture* set to *Radial* gives us this output.

[image]

If we feed this into a *Noise Texture* we get this.

[image]

We can mix in a bit of the regular coordinate space to give some irregularity.

[image]

And here I've used this output to drive the base color between two shades of brown, the roughness, and a *Bump Node*.  I've also used a bit of regular ol' anisotropy.

[image]

And since these are generated coordinates based on a bounding box around your mesh, you can easily use this on any size of gear.

[image]