# Metal machined sunburst effect for watch dail

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I would like to create the following effect on a watch I'm rendering.
Can anybody help me? especially the machined line to the centre is hard for me to create.
the rest I use the anisotropic in the Principled shader.

Thanks for the help.

Dennis

[image: This effect]

Comment: Does this help? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208714/how-do-i-create-a-radial-metallic-gear-material-procedurally

Comment: Awesome! I will try that. Thank you!